# PostMessage function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, postmessage

I'm using this code in C++ to send a key events to different applications.

```
struct extraKeyInfo
{
    unsigned short repeatCount;
    unsigned char scanCode;
    bool extendedKey, prevKeyState, transitionState;

    operator unsigned int()
    {
        return repeatCount | (scanCode << 16) | (extendedKey << 24) |
            (prevKeyState << 30) | (transitionState << 31);
    }
};
void SendK(HWND wnd, Char ch, DWORD del)
{
    short vkCode = LOBYTE(VkKeyScan(ch));
    extraKeyInfo lParam = {};
    lParam.scanCode = MapVirtualKey(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    PostMessage(wnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lParam);
    lParam.repeatCount = 1;
    lParam.prevKeyState = true;
    lParam.transitionState = true;
    Sleep(del);
    PostMessage(wnd, WM_KEYUP, vkCode, lParam);
}
```

I really need to use THIS method in C#. I know that i can import PostMessage and MapVirtualKey functions from user32.dll like this

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
```

But I'm stuck with lParam variable. I don't know how to convert those flags bits in C#. There must be a way.

**Edit. Done and done**
After Jashaszun's little advice.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);
    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0x00;
    const uint MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK = 0x01;
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x02;
    const uint MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX = 0x03;
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX = 0x04;
class extraKeyInfo
    {
        public ushort repeatCount;
        public char scanCode;
        public ushort extendedKey, prevKeyState, transitionState;

        public int getint()
        {
            return repeatCount | (scanCode << 16) | (extendedKey << 24) |
                (prevKeyState << 30) | (transitionState << 31);
        }
    };
    public static void SendK(IntPtr wnd, Char ch, Int32 del)
    {
        uint vkCode = (byte)(VkKeyScan(ch));
        extraKeyInfo lParam = new extraKeyInfo();
        lParam.scanCode = (char)MapVirtualKey(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
        PostMessage(wnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vkCode, lParam.getint());
        lParam.repeatCount = 1;
        lParam.prevKeyState = 1;
        lParam.transitionState = 1;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(del);
        PostMessage(wnd, WM_KEYUP, vkCode, lParam.getint());
    }
```

SendK function will send a specified char to a specified window with a specified hold delay.

Comment: Why not create a C# class `ExtraKeyInfo` that has a `getInt()` function that does the same thing as `extraKeyInfo.operator int()`, and then pass your `ExtraKeyInfo.getInt()` as `lParam`?